# CouchDb: How to delete documents older > 6 month?

Tags: shell, couchdb

I have the problem that I like to "automagically" delete documents in my couch, which are at least 6 month old. 
My CouchDb instance runs on a linux server, is there any way to achieve this quite simple (like writing a simple 2-line shell script) ?

Comment: I updated my post. I hope it will help you

Comment: V-Light is right that you can't do this without first having (1) timestamps in all your documents, and (2) queries prepared to search by timestamp. However, once/if you've got that, I use `jss` for one-off bulk Couch work. Basically: `curl --silent $some_query | jss - '{_id: $._id, _rev:$._rev, _deleted:true}' --bulk-docs | curl --silent $some_db/_bulk_dos`

Comment: Since it is very hard to find with google, here is the link to jss: https://github.com/iriscouch/jss

Comment: I'm thinking about a PHP-CLI-based approach now, but the idea about storing the document's creation date was the right idea in my opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write an update function in couchdb that deletes a doc on certain criteria ( you can use params while calling the function) :
 http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers#Creating_an_Update_Handler

(look at "in-place" and imagine setting "_delete:true").

something like

```
"deletefunc":
...
if(doc.created_at<req.query.mindate) {
  doc._deleted:true;
  return [doc, "deleted"]
}
```

and calling 
    ...db/_design/updatefuncdesigndoc/_update/deletefunc/dok_id_x?mindate=20110816

The only work is: calling each doc in a database explicit with this function (calling _all_docs or _changes first)

Comment: Thank you.Update function was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

As long as I know, CouchDB stores each database (with all documents) in a **single file** (). So you will be not able to find specific doc by its name or added-datetime.

**UPDATE:**

I think  the only way would be to add a "_doc_created" (or "_doc_established") field to each document, with a timestamp (similarity to SQLs `NOW()`). Then create a view which shows only documents IDs an values of "_doc_created" fields:

e.G.

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc._doc_created, doc._id); 
  //or just emit(doc._doc_created) 'couse views alsways return docIDs
}
```

and then write a script (e.G. a *shell-script*) which gets all these IDs and DATEs (via *curl*), filters it and then (again via *curl*) DELETEs all the docs from database which `_doc_crated` datetime is older than 6 month from now

Comment: +1. Unlike most filesystems, and systems like RoR, CouchDB does not require or suggest that you keep timestamps in your data. That is unfortunate, because successful applications (i.e. those that "live" months or years) almost always need that information later.  Like planting a tree, the next-best time to clean data is now. Since CouchDB is relaxed, you can add timestamps to your records as needed and query and delete them as needed.

Comment: While the approach of adding a timestamp is good, the suggested approach to running the 'purge script' is a pretty complex approach.  See the 'update function in couchdb' for an approach that is simpler and leverages the appropriate couchdb features.